# Varioref does not refer to the same page in the right way, i.e. 'on this page'

Tags: cross-referencing, varioref

I've got a problem with the `varioref` package:

Whenever I want to refer to something that is on the same page as the reference, `varioref` normally printed something like 'X on this page' or 'X auf dieser Seite' (German) (X = number of label) , but today I tried to use `varioref` again (after I reinstalled MiKTeX because of an API 1113 Error or something concerning the update manager after an update -- fixed it \o/) and I only got 'X on page Y' (Y = page number) when the reference was on the same page as what I wanted to refer to. If there's something on the next or former page, the output is correct (e.g. 'X on the previous page').

Here's a (hopefully more or less) minimal example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{varioref} 
\begin{document}
\section{Bla}\label{bla}
Haha, \vref{bla}. {\reftextcurrent} \clearpage
Haha, \vref{bla}.
\end{document}
```

And what I get using pdfTeX is:

> %%%%%%%%%%%% Page 1
>
> 1 Bla Haha, 1 on page 1. on this page
>
> %%%%%%%%%%%% Page 2
>
> Haha, 1 on the previous page.

(I only included the `{\reftextcurrent}` to see whether the text `varioref` normally used, might have been redefined accidentally. )

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to page 1 of the `varioref` documentation, `\reftextcurrent` is only used by the `\vpageref` command if label and reference fall on the same page --  `\vref` will only produce a `\ref` (i.e., the section number) in this case.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{varioref} 
\begin{document}
\section{Bla}\label{bla}
Haha, \vref{bla}.
Haha, \vpageref{bla}.
\clearpage
Haha, \vref{bla}.
Haha, \vpageref{bla}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, OK, it seems I missed that, sorry (although I definitely read the documentation, I'm not that much of a noob), but be that as it may, what I get on the first page of the pdf from your example is: "Haha, 1 on page 1. Haha, on page 1." while I should get "Haha, 1. Haha, on page 1.", shouldn't I?

Comment: Well, I get "Haha, 1. Haha, on the current page." Package versions: `babel` 3.8l, `varioref` 1.4w.

Comment: Hmmm, I've got `babel` 3.8m and `varioref` 1.4y. It shouldn't be a matter of actuality then... This is kinda odd.

Comment: To the contrary: I'm using TeXlive 2011, but for whatever reason this TeX distribution shipped with an old version of `varioref` (!). It may well be that something broke in the newer version.

Comment: I just made an interesting observation: If I also load `hyperref`in addition to (and after) `varioref`, the output is right: No mention of the page number if the object of interest is on the same page as the reference, just like it should be. Or is this a feature of `hyperref` itself? I normally don't use it and loaded it as is (`\usepackage{hyperref}`).